# How could i encapsulate the integer number and the time it was generated ?

Tags: java, class, random, time

This is the random number generator.

```
package mynum;

import java.util.Random;

public class MyNum {

static Random number = new Random();


public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i =0; i < 1 ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println( genRandom());
    }

}
public static int genRandom(){
    return number.nextInt(200);
}

}
```

This is the time

```
package time;

public class Time {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.nanoTime());
}

}
```

how could i put these two in my new class called Node. In the Node class i want to get the random number and the time it was genertated together.

For example

Number 178 Time 10988393883

Number 163 Time 10299383773

Comment: just generate the timestamp the same way you are generating the number attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a mechanism through which the actual time value can be obtained (not just printed) from the `Time` class, something along the lines of:

```
public static long time() {
    return System.nanoTime();
}
```

Then the `Node` class should be simple:

```
class Node {
    private int num;
    private long time;

    public Node() {
        num = MyNum.genRandom();
        time = Time.time();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Number " + num + " Time " + time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy.  Simple structure.

```
public class Node {

    private static final Random RNG = new Random();

    public static String generateRandom() {
        return "Number " + RNG.nextInt(200) + " Time " + System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

If you want to actually be object-oriented rather than simply printing:

```
public class Node {

    private static final Random RNG = new Random();

    private final int number;
    private final long timeGenerated;

    public Node() {
        number = RNG.nextInt(200);
        timeGenerated = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public long getTimeGenerated() {
        return timeGenerated;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Number " + number + " Time " + timeGenerated;
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to access number and time seperatly?

Comment: @dognose Added to the answer.  That wasn't part of the question, however, which was about printing both together.

Comment: Thanks figured it out.